# Get the Error: connect ECONNREFUSED while making active MQ Connection?

Tags: java, node.js, activemq-classic

Activemq.xml has Following configuration using discover Agent

```
  <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://localhost:61616" discoveryUri="multicast://default?group=TestPartition"/>
```

I am using stomp module of node.js. Now i need to make the connection to my active mq broker. Not getting how to make the connection
 using configured discover agent and get the below error

```
 error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:769:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:760:19)error name: Error

events.js:71
    throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
               ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:769:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:760:19)
```

Earlier  i was using below configuarion(no group was mentioned)
 and was able to make the connection successfully

```
 <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://localhost:61616" discoveryUri="multicast://default"/>
```

Code i was using to make the connection

```
    var stomp = require("stomp");
    var  stompClient = new stomp.Stomp("localhost", 8161);
    var destHeaders = {
        destination: '/topic/testTopic',
        ack: 'acknowledgeResp'

    };
    client.connect();
    client.on('connected', function() {
        client.subscribe(destHeaders);
       });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to connect a STOMP client to an Openwire transport connector which of course won't work as they are two different protocols.  You need to configure a STOMP transport connector for your STOMP clients to connect to.

```
 <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://localhost:61613"/>
```